# How do I kill Hans Volter?

Tags: killing-floor-2

Boss is near impossible to kill, let alone solo.   Either the gas grenades get me, or it's his lifedrain, or his crazy run speed. As a low level medic I struggle because I can only run and getting a shot off while running is very risky.

What is the best way to defeat Hans Volter? I tried pumping AA-12 shots into him, dbarrels, the eviscerator, all are so ineffective I've given up trying to beat Hans.

Comment: I've got, what I assume is, close.  I feel your pain!  Tips I've seen are to never get close to him, so Range seems to be the key, as if you are close he will just grab you and life-suck you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to break this down into parts, for each of his abilities.

When Hans uses his **gas grenades**, they can be avoided by simply running away from them before they explode - not too sure why your having too much trouble with this.

Sometimes he **emits gas from himself** (farts as my party likes to call it) which you can't really avoid if he has just sprinted up to you. Best option from there is to get people to heal you to counter the effect. Also make sure to not stand in the gas he creates, as this deals extra damage if you do.

When he throws out his smoke grenades (triggered by reaching certain amount of health)**let him heal.** He has a huge damage reduction buff before he heals. You're just wasting bullets if you shoot at him before he can heal and lose the buff he gets.

When **someone does get grabbed, heal them!** Don't shoot him while he is healing, as he always heals to full health.

When he is in his critically damaged phase (**shooting at you with his guns**), make sure to use elevation and corners to your advantage. **Do not run down corridors or open areas,** as he can just pelt lead at you while you do so. It's all about breaking his line of sight (kiting him effectively) and unloading on him when the opportunity presents itself.

You can tell how injured he is by the colour he appears as, going from green to red with sparks. He can be killed in his form with of red with sparks only, from what I've seen so far.

Finally, don't let him melee you. It hurts. **A lot.** Try to use elevation and corners, once again. However, don't lead him off away from your party.

I won't deny that **this boss is hard** (after all, it is a boss). He is the right level of difficulty though, and doesn't need too much tweaking in my opinion.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can only add for single player tactics.
Hans isn't the brightest and it's fairly easy to put an object between him and yourself.
Hans will constantly chase you so running around a bus or other obstacle will give you enough time to heal yourself. I usually try to heal when health drops just below 80.
Additionally, Hans has a fairly slow turning circle, so if you are the berserker class run rings around him.
Try to keep another primary weapon as a backup for when your primary weapon runs out of ammo. This will probably be something light, but it's still more effective than a pistol.
Good luck!

Comment: If your team has enough firepower you can (and should) break the shield to avoid having him heal. Although your answer might predate that change.

Answer (score 1):

Just soloed him today, with berserker.

All you need to do is kite him, dodge his grenades and shots, learn the quotes when he tries to drain health and just run until he does something else.

There's not much room for error while soloing him, berserker was good because he has increased movement speed, but its also a down side since you run all the time, he might fall behind too much and find a short cut. Don't melee him even if you are berserker.

I used a flamethrower, set him on fire and ran.

Answer (score 1):

Level 14medic and a level one zerker here. Solo with melee is viable on normal, I haven't tried on higher. I just did it twice in a row. Get a Pulverizer and hide behind a door way, block his melee, alt fire and run to the next, repeat that for a magazine and he will rush you. Repeat that 4 times. Win. By the way, EMPs don't do shiz against him.

With a medic, grab your medic AR, SMG and Pistol. WHat you want to do is kite like a mofo. Run to a door way, look back and wait to see him. He should throw nades, fire 20 full auto rounds max, then run. Keep running for a while so he recharges his nades, then repeat. Move in a little loop constantly looking for ammo. Drop healing grenades while doing so, he should run into them and take acid damage. Save one for when he rushes you. Run to a spot with a turn or door way and drop it there, wait till he milks you then repeat. Always look for ammo. Always look for armour.

Commando is the same minus the health nades, you need to aim them a bit.

Support? AA12. take him down till he charges with something else. AS he pops smoke, start unloading with the AA12. Even with the 85% damage reduction, he can still die from a full mag of that beast. Enjoy doing this 4 times faster than anyone else.

To do that in MP you need to give the entire team AA12s. Good luck organizing that with pubbies.

Comment: As support, if you have the "Fast reload" perk, the M4 is more powerful than the AA12. AA12 is good for when you don't have the perk.

Answer (score -2):

Here i answer you (not solo):

:)

If u want to solo", i think Berserk is the best option!

Comment: Please summarize the video's information as it pertains to this question.  That way, if this video ever goes down, your answer is still valid.